# Avoid fetch all the entity during handleRequest in Symfony 4

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation

I created a form to edit only two properties of an entity that has four, two of which are relationships to many other entities.

I use the form to modify the two string data.

When handleRequest is run after the form submission in my Controller, my page loads slowly and consumes a lot of memory.
After a search, this is due to the fact that the handleRequest retrieves the content of all the properties of the modified entity for the validation.

Is it possible to modify certain properties of an entity without having handleRequest load all the data of the entity?

Let me give you an example of my files:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TracteurRepository")
 */
class Tracteur
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=30)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max=30)
     * @Assert\Type("string")
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max=10)
     * @Assert\Type("string")
     */
    private $tag;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\AlerteTracteur", mappedBy="tracteur", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $alertes;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Poslog", mappedBy="tracteur")
     */
    private $poslogs;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->alertes = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->poslogs = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTag(): ?string
    {
        return $this->tag;
    }

    public function setTag(?string $tag): self
    {
        $this->tag = $tag;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|AlerteTracteur[]
     */
    public function getAlertes(): Collection
    {
        return $this->alertes;
    }

    public function addAlerte(AlerteTracteur $alerte): self
    {
        if (!$this->alertes->contains($alerte)) {
            $this->alertes[] = $alerte;
            $alerte->setTracteur($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAlerte(AlerteTracteur $alerte): self
    {
        if ($this->alertes->contains($alerte)) {
            $this->alertes->removeElement($alerte);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($alerte->getTracteur() === $this) {
                $alerte->setTracteur(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Poslog[]
     */
    public function getPoslogs(?RechercheInformations $recherche): Collection
    {
        $poslogs = $this->poslogs;

        if(!empty($recherche)){
            $criteria = Criteria::create()
                ->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->andX(
                    Criteria::expr()->lte('dateCreation', $recherche->getDateFin()),
                    Criteria::expr()->gte('dateCreation', $recherche->getDateDebut())
                ))
            ;

            $poslogs = $poslogs->matching($criteria);
        }

        return $poslogs;
    }

    public function addPoslog(Poslog $poslog): self
    {
        if (!$this->poslogs->contains($poslog)) {
            $this->poslogs[] = $poslog;
            $poslog->setTracteur($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removePoslog(Poslog $poslog): self
    {
        if ($this->poslogs->contains($poslog)) {
            $this->poslogs->removeElement($poslog);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($poslog->getTracteur() === $this) {
                $poslog->setTracteur(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

My form:

```
class TracteurType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nom', TextType::class, [
                "required" => true,
            ])
            ->add('tag', TextType::class, [
                "required" => true,
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Tracteur::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/parametrage/tracteur/{id}/editer", name="tracteur_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, int $id): Response
    {
        $tracteur = $this->em->getRepository(Tracteur::class)->findTracteur($id);

        $form = $this->createForm(TracteurType::class, $tracteur);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->em->persist($tracteur);
            $this->em->flush();
        }

        return $this->render('tracteur/edit.html.twig', [
            'page' => 'tracteurs',
            'tracteur' => $tracteur,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

This is the backtrace of the query which load the relation:

```
#   File/Call
1   Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\LoggerChain->startQuery (line 894)
2   Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->executeQuery (line 1818)
3   Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Entity\BasicEntityPersister->getOneToManyStatement (line 1758)
4   Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Entity\BasicEntityPersister->loadOneToManyCollection (line 2932)
5   Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->loadCollection (line 704)
6   Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection->doInitialize (line 213)
7   Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection->initialize (line 280)
8   Doctrine\Common\Collections\AbstractLazyCollection->getIterator (line 45)
9   Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\AllValidator->validate (line 731)
10  Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveContextualValidator->validateInGroup (line 593)
11  Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveContextualValidator->validateGenericNode (line 507)
12  Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveContextualValidator->validateClassNode (line 310)
13  Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveContextualValidator->validateObject (line 135)
14  Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveContextualValidator->validate (line 58)
15  Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\Constraints\FormValidator->validate (line 731)
16  Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveContextualValidator->validateInGroup (line 485)
17  Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveContextualValidator->validateClassNode (line 310)
18  Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveContextualValidator->validateObject (line 135)
19  Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveContextualValidator->validate (line 93)
20  Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveValidator->validate (line 66)
21  Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\TraceableValidator->validate (line 50)
22  Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\EventListener\ValidationListener->validateForm (line 230)
23  Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->callListeners (line 59)
24  Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch (line 33)
25  Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ImmutableEventDispatcher->dispatch (line 670)
26  Symfony\Component\Form\Form->submit (line 109)
27  Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\HttpFoundation\HttpFoundationRequestHandler->handleRequest (line 492)
28  Symfony\Component\Form\Form->handleRequest (line 133)
29  App\Controller\TracteurController->edit (line 145)
30  Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw (line 67)
31  Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle (line 191)
32  Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle (line 27)
enter code here
```

Comment: is it really ```handleRequest``` and not ```$form->isValid``` which triggers the loading of the lazy assocs? can you tell which part of handleRequest is responsible for it?

Comment: I confirm, the loading of the relation is initialized by handleRequest. You can see the backtrace of the query in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Putting doctrine's **fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"** or **fetch="LAZY"** on mapping should do the trick

Comment: I tested with fetch="EXTRA_LAZY" and fetch="LAZY" but handleRequest still loads all the data of the entity.

Comment: I remember handleRequest has some really weird interactions with entities I'll edit my answer if I figure something else